# Bitwise operator on pointer to class?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, ifstream, readfile

I spent a day digging in a legacy code of a previous guy in the project, and also I've searched about bitwise operator I still cannot clearly understand the code line with bitwise opearator:

```
input >> *graph;
```

I can compile and run, however, I put 2 printf functions for your remark: it can print "11111" and after that "4", but can never print "2222", so there must be something wrong with the bitwise operator line. How can I solve this problem?

`*graph` is a pointer points to an object of class GGraph:

```
class GGraph{
public:
GGraph();

~GGraph();
void addNode ( GNodeData nodedata, GNodeOrGroup orgroup = GNOGROUP );
void delNode (); //code...........
};
```

FYI: this is part of the program to return the frequent pattern in a graph data set (graph mining). The chunk of code I ask here is only a procedure to open and read graph data information from a file. Graph data is something like this:

```
t # 0
v 0 0
v 1 0
...
(all the vertices with their labels)
e 0 1 3
e 1 2 3
...
(all the edges with the vetices they connect and their labels)
t # 1 (graph No.2)
....
```

This is the chunk of code that the program cannot pass at run time:

```
void GDatabase::read ( string filename )
    {
        char header[100];
        ifstream input ( filename.c_str () );
        GGraph *graph = new GGraph ();

        input.getline ( header, 100 ); // we assume a header before each graph
        printf("%s", header);

    //    char c;
    //    c = input.get();
    //    while (input) {
    //        std::cout << c;
    //        c = input.get();}

        getchar();
        printf("11111111111");
        printf("\n%d",sizeof(graph));

        input >> *graph;
        printf("2222222222");
        while ( !input.eof () ) {
            process ( graph );
            graphs.push_back ( graph );
            graph = new GGraph ();
            input.getline ( header, 100 );
            input >> *graph;
        }
        delete graph;     
        input.close ();
    }
```

**EDIT: As suggested this ">>" is actually stream extractor, I found this definition of the operator:**

```
istream& operator>>(istream& stream, GGraph &graph )
{
  char m;
  GNodeData nd;
  GEdgeData ed;
  GNodeOrGroup og;
  GNodeID ni, ni1, ni2;

  m = stream.get ();

  if ( stream.eof () )
    return stream;

  while ( !stream.eof () && m == 'v' ) {
    stream >> ni;
    stream >> nd;
    stream >> og;
    graph.addNode ( nd, og );
    do {
      m = stream.get (); // get end of line
    } 
    while ( m != '\n' ); 
    m = stream.get ();
  }
  while ( !stream.eof () && m == 'e' ) {
    stream >> ni1;
    stream >> ni2;
    stream >> ed;
    graph.addEdge ( ni1, ni2, ed );
    do {
      m = stream.get (); // get end of line
    }
    while ( m != '\n' ); 
    m = stream.get ();
  }

  stream.unget (); 
  stream.clear (); // also unput eof if we read 

  return stream;
}
```

Comment: That bitwise operator is probably actually a stream extraction operator. Can you search for `operator >>` somewhere in the code?

Comment: The comment part is the part I added to check if there's anything to the ifstream input, it does print out all the content of the file. But if I run that part of code, there's nothing left in the graph data file for the program to continue processing...

Comment: After reading from the `ifstream` once, you would have to seek it back to the beginning of the file in order to read it a second time.

Comment: This extractor function totally munges up handling of eof (and will go into an infinite loop if the stream has an error condition other than eof)

Comment: @MattMcNabb  Yes I think the culprit is this one: do {m = stream.get ();} while ( m != '\n' );
I debug step by step. It never gets a new line "\n" from the stream, and it did fell into infinite loop. How to get the new line character from stream?

Comment: If there is no newline in the stream then it can never get one. This whole function needs to be replaced really. Can you post a sample of the file that is being read?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/MHQDB2ur <<< Content of the file being read. I see that it has CRLF for each line. This is link to the original file: https://copy.com/S8n12n0p4hRfWJf3

Answer (score 2):

> input >> *graph;

This is not a bitwise operator.  It is an stream extraction operator.  Somewhere in the code, there has to be an `operator>>` defined that takes a stream and GGraph as input, eg:

```
template<class CharT, class Traits = std::char_traits<CharT> >
std::basic_istream<CharT, Traits>& operator>>(std::basic_istream<CharT, Traits> &in, GGraph &graph)
{
    // read values from in and store them in graph as needed...
    return in;
}
```

So this line:

```
input >> *graph;
```

Is actually calling:

```
operator>>(input, *graph);
```

Comment: THank you, yes I found 2 lines, perhaps this is what you mean:
istream& operator>>(istream& stream, GGraph &graph );
ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, GGraph &graph );
The code for them is quite long :)

Comment: There you go then.  So what is the actual problem?

Comment: Actually it **is** a bitwise operator that has been overloaded with a completely unrelated semantic just because it looks funky and has a decent priority for that.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I made an edit with the details of the operator definition in the question. The problem is I cannot pass the stream reading process... :)